# whose error? Default operator= or vector expending

Tags: c++, vector

here is my code:
I'm so sorry my code is too long, the important part is constructor of skiplist and listnode. And I got segmentation error.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stack> 

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class skiplist
{
#define MAXSPAN 3
#define MINSPAN 2
public:
    typedef T datatype;
    typedef struct listnode {
        datatype data;
        size_t span;
        listnode* nextnode;
        listnode* belownode;
        listnode(T data) :
            data(data),
            span(1),
            nextnode(nullptr),
            belownode(nullptr)
        {}
        listnode& operator=(listnode& other) {
            memcpy(this, &other, sizeof(listnode));
        }
    } listnode;
    struct iterator {
    public:
        listnode* ptr;
        iterator() : ptr(nullptr) {}
        iterator(listnode* p) : ptr(p) {}
        bool operator==(iterator& other) { return ptr == other.ptr; }
        iterator& operator++() {
            ptr = ptr->nextnode;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    skiplist() :
        _size(0),
        _end(nullptr),
        _begin(nullptr)
    {
        //content.reserve(1000);
        content.emplace_back(listnode(-1));
        _head = &content[content.size() - 1];
        printf("head next:%p\n", _head->nextnode);
    }

    bool insert(datatype data) {
        if (_size > 0 && _head->data == data)
            return false;
        if (_size == 0)
        {
            content.emplace_back(listnode(data));
            _head->belownode = &content[content.size() - 1];
            _head->data = data;
            _head->span = 1;
            printf("head next:%p\n", _head->nextnode);
            _size = 1;
            _begin = _head->belownode;
            return true;
        }
        listnode* tmp;
        stack<listnode*> st;
        for (tmp = _head; tmp->belownode != nullptr; tmp = tmp->belownode) {
            while (tmp->nextnode != _end && tmp->nextnode->data < data)
                tmp = tmp->nextnode;
            if (tmp->nextnode != _end && tmp->nextnode->data == data)
                return false;
            st.push(tmp);

        }
        // the new data is least
        if (tmp->data > data) {
            _size++;
            content.emplace_back(listnode(data));
            _begin = &content[content.size() - 1];
            _begin->nextnode = tmp;
            tmp = st.top();
            tmp->belownode = _begin;
        }
        else
        {
            while (tmp->nextnode != _end && tmp->nextnode->data < data)
                tmp = tmp->nextnode;
            if (tmp->nextnode != _end && tmp->nextnode->data == data)
                return false;
            _size++;
            content.emplace_back(listnode(data));
            content[content.size() - 1].nextnode = tmp->nextnode;
            tmp->nextnode = &content[content.size() - 1];
        }
        tmp = st.top();
        tmp->span++;
        while (!st.empty()) {
            tmp = st.top();
            st.pop();
            if (tmp->data > data)
                tmp->data = data;
            if (tmp->span > MAXSPAN) { //4 nodes
                printf("split\n");
                listnode* pivot = tmp->belownode->nextnode->nextnode;
                datatype newnode = pivot->data;
                content.emplace_back(listnode(newnode));
                listnode* new_node_ptr = &content[content.size() - 1];
                new_node_ptr->span = MINSPAN;
                tmp->span = MINSPAN;
                new_node_ptr->belownode = pivot;
                new_node_ptr->nextnode = tmp->nextnode;
                tmp->nextnode = new_node_ptr;
                if (!st.empty()) {
                    tmp = st.top();
                    tmp->span++;
                }
                else {
                    content.push_back(listnode(_head->data));
                    tmp = _head;
                    _head = &content[content.size() - 1];
                    _head->span = 2;
                    _head->belownode = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // end iterator
    const iterator end() { return end_iter; }

    // find 
    iterator find(datatype data) {
        iterator iter(_end);
        if (_size == 0)
            return iter;
        listnode* tmp;
        for (tmp = _head; tmp != nullptr; tmp = tmp->belownode) {
            while (tmp->nextnode != _end && tmp->nextnode->data <= data)
                tmp = tmp->nextnode;
        }
        if (tmp->data == data) {
            iter.ptr = tmp;
        }
        return iter;
    }

    // count
    int count(datatype data) { return find(data) != _end; }

    // erase
    bool erase(datatype data) {

    }

    bool erase(iterator iter) {

    }

    bool empty() { return _size == 0; }

    size_t size() { return _size; }

    void clear() {
        _head = &content[0];
        _begin = _end;
        _size = 0;
        content.resize(1);
    }

    void print() {
        listnode* tmp, * printptr;
        for (tmp = _head; tmp != nullptr; tmp = tmp->belownode) {
            for (printptr = tmp; printptr != nullptr; printptr = printptr->nextnode) {
                printf("data=%d span=%zd\n", printptr->data, printptr->span);
                //printf("ptr next=%p below=%p\n", printptr->nextnode, printptr->belownode);
            }
            printf("========\n");
        }
        printf("size=%d\n", _size);
    }
private:
    listnode* _begin;
    listnode* _head;
    const listnode* _end;
    size_t _size;
    iterator end_iter;
public:
    vector<listnode> content;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    skiplist<int> list0;
    //freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int a[200] = {};

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        list0.insert(i + 1);
        list0.print();
    }
    /*
    printf("data=%d span=%d next=%p below=%p\n", list0.content[1].data,
        list0.content[1].span, list0.content[1].nextnode, list0.content[1].belownode
    );*/
    list0.print();
    return 0;
}
```

After I wrote them, I got some debugging info like below:
head next:0000000000000000
head next:DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
I'm shocked that the _head->nextnode was changed! But after adding `content.reserve(1000);` The mysterious bug disappeared!!
where does this error come from? Default operator= or vector expending?(not only the _head, but also any of the item could be changed while vector expanding.
you can make the loop longer such as 1000.
(the content should be private if not in debugging)

Comment: Value `DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD` is used by some compilers in debug mode to indicate "not initialized value".

Comment: using `memcpy` in  `operator=`  is suspicious, but what makes it UB to call it for sure is that its declared to returns something but it misses a `return`

Comment: do not ignore warnings !! https://godbolt.org/z/oaP4zdqTE

Comment: Lots of warning and address sanitizer finds issue: https://godbolt.org/z/WPK1MqesT

Comment: `_head` becomes invalid when `content` grows, as do all other pointers to vector elements. Store indices instead of pointers.

Comment: On a side note, `content[content.size() - 1]` is usually spelled `content.back()`.

Comment: `skiplist<std::string>` -- Your class is entirely broken with this one declaration.  Do not use `memcpy`, plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in the code, a major one is that you store pointers to elements in the vector while adding elements to it. Thats not going to work. Inserting into a vector potentially invalidates iterators to elements (and also pointers). The simple and lazy fix is `std::list` because it has stable iterators, though I rather recommend to refactor the whole code so you no longer rely on pointers to elements of the vector.

It works when you call `content.reserve(1000);` because then the vector does not need to reallocate. Only when adding more than 1000 elements the pointers would get invalid. That however only delays the problem, and is a waste of memory.

The next biggest issue in the code is that you have several functions that are declared to return something but fail to do so. Calling any of those functions is undefined behavior (even when the return value is not used!).